Shape Keys act differently after exporting a .blend file as .glb
I'm importing a .blend file (that has been exported from CC4) and then converting it to .glb  but the shape keys in the .glb act different as compared to the ones in the blend file. How do I get the shape keys to act exactly the same in .glb?
